# Two sequences $a$ and $b$ for which $\Delta a_n = \Delta b _n$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Find two different sequences $a$ and $b$ for which $\Delta a_n = \Delta b_n$ for all of $n$.

This is my first time doing recurrence relations, so if anyone could provide some thorough and clear hints/examples, it would be great.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* $\Delta a_n = \Delta b _n$ implies $\Delta (a_n - b _n)=0$. What does this imply about $a_n - b _n$?

Comment: Does that mean that $a_n - b_n $ will be equal to $0$?

Comment: @user134574, no, think about it. What examples do you know of a sequence $c_n$ such that $\Delta c_n =0$? The difference operator $\Delta$ is like differentiation. There are non-zero functions whose derivative is zero, right?

Comment: im sorry, i still dont understand the hint. To be honest, this is the first encounter I've had where $\Delta x_n =0 $. I can't quite understand.. would you mind elaborating, or giving an example?

Answer (score 0):

If a step from a(n) to a(n+1) size delta is always the same as a the step from b(n) to b(n+1), then starting from a(1) and going k steps further to a(k+1) should also be true for the b-sequence: from b(1) to b(k+1). So, in a plot, they rise in parallel. How does one translate that analytically?